# Translation of product in minicart and checkout - magento 2.x

Tags: product, checkout, translate

I have the following problem with translation of product in minicart and checkout on Magento 2.x:
 When I add product in minicart on one language(for example English) and later, if I change the language to German, the product still is shown in English. Product is added for both store views - English and German. Is there are any way to fix this?

Comment: How did you install German language? Did you deploy with German language? What contents are displayed or not in German/English language in Product page?

Comment: Which command used for deploy static content?

Comment: All texts in minicart are in selected language only the description of product still to be in wrong language. I has set different text for both languages(store view). Step to reproduce problem: 
- select English language
- add product to minicart - here all is Ok
- change language to German - all site are translate , only description of product are still to be English(this is problem).
if delete minicart and add product under German language then the product's description is ok  ,but when switch again to English product still to be in German.

Comment: If it is not default magento theme, compare the respective files for minicart of your theme with default theme. Custom theme might not have its translation coding.

Comment: I'm using custom maganto theme. But also test the case in default luma theme(in other magento installation 2.1.4)   and the problem still exist. Is it possible this to be default behavior of minicart /checkout , if one time the product put in to cart to be not change(price/language/description) ?